# What's the purpose of control-label?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap. The `control-label` class seems to be undocumented at the bootstrap 3 website and i have noticed it just accidentally in the examples.

Could anyone explain it's purpose or guide me where I can get more info on it?

Comment: look at **http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms** -> it is used as class for `<label>` along with `<form>` so you can have nice aligned forms without using `<table>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`control-label` is useful when we create **forms**. At the time of creation, you may come across in such situation like your text field is just after the completion of label.

So you have to write CSS to make it more attractive.

In bootstrap, they have provided class called `control-label` whose work is to automatically set the label. So that label and text field looks better and we don't have to write CSS for that.

CSS of `.control-label`:

```
.control-label{margin-bottom:0;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-bottom:0;
  text-align:right;
  color:#a94442;    

  }
```

**NOTE** : Here I have not include `padding` because `padding` may vary according to screen size.

If you want to know more about it, just look at that [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/108623).You will at least get some idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

It's for labeling a `.form-group`. For `.form-horizontal` it does

```
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 7px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

... mainly for right-aligned labels.